# Unable to Read JSON File

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON file below:

```
{"myArea":[{
 "name": "ny 01",
 "data": [63]
}]}
```

I use the code below to retrieve the data:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {   
  $.getJSON('area.json',function(area){
    console.log(area[0][0]);
  });   
});
```

However the data is not being retrieved. Console log says [object object] or undefined name when trying `console.log(area[0])` or `console.log(area[0].name)`. What is the proper way to access the data?

Comment: Try: `console.log(area.myArea[0])`

Comment: Based on what you've posted here, I expect you need to get `area["myArea"]` (or just `area.myArea`) first. You aren't referring to the `myArea` array anywhere in your code.

Comment: `console.log(area.myArea[0])` worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted code, `area` has one property named `myArea`.

`console.log(area.myArea)` would give you:

```
[{"name": "ny 01", "data": [63]}]
```

`console.log(area.myArea[0]` would give you:

```
{"name": "ny 01", "data": [63]}
```

To access `data` of the first element:

`console.log(area.myArea[0].data[0]`

would give you `63`

Answer (score 2):

Your root JSON object is an 'object'! You can access properties by using `area['name']` or `area.name` (where *name* is a valid key).

In your case, you have a key called `myArea`: `area['myArea']`.

The result of this expression will be the following array (expressed in JSON here):

```
[{
 "name": "ny 01",
 "data": [63]
}]
```

Now, you can grab the first element from the `myArea` array by using `area['myAray'][0]`.
This will result in the following object being returned:

```
{
 "name": "ny 01",
 "data": [63]
}
```

Accessing the data is rather easy now (but pay attention to *data*, it is an array!)

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
  $.getJSON('area.json',function(area){
    console.log(area['myArea'][0]['name']);    "ny 01"
    console.log(area['myArea'][0]['data'][0]); 63
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating "area" like an array (by trying to access the item with index zero) but it is an object.  Instead try accessing the "myArea" attribute of the object.

```javascript
var area = {"myArea":[{
  "name": "ny 01",
  "data": [63]
}]};

area[0]; // => undefined, because there is no attribute with key "0".
area['myArea']; // => [{name:"ny 01",...}], same as "area.myArea".
```